# Removing elements from a dynamic JSON

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON used as base template which is uploaded in a web platform by the administrator:

```
{
    "age": 0,
    "name": "string",
    "interest": "string",
    "address": "string",
    "personalId": 0
}
```

Then users can create their own JSON schema based on the base template and upload them. These JSON files are all different by each other, but they have in common all the fields in the base template they are derived. The fields can also be in a different order.
In example:

```
{
    "age": 23,
    "weight":65,
    "name": "Emily",
    "gender":"Female",
    "interest": "graphic design",
    "address": "Elm street",
    "personalId": 916742
}
```

...another:

```
{
    "age": 39,
    "name": "John",
    "weight": 77,
    "interest": "graphic design",
    "address": "Elm street",
    "gender": "Male",
    "personalId": 916742,
    "education": "University",
    "children": [{
        "name": "Katie",
        "gender": "Female"
    }, {
        "name": "Greg",
        "gender": "Male"
    }]
    "someOtherInfo": "lorem ipsum"
}
```

what I'm trying to do is to remove, from each of the JSON I will receive, all the field which are not present in the base template.

In example from the first entry I will have:

```
{
    "age": 23,
    "name": "Emily",
    "interest": "graphic design",
    "address": "Elm street",
    "personalId": 916742
}
```

The number of fields in the JSON can reach also 300~400 different fields, and the base template contains ~200 fields.
The fields of the base template are all at the first level, no nested fields, and, as I've stored in a database table I could have them also as a list of strings.

Can be achieved using a dynamic object in an efficient way?

Comment: deserialize it as a `Dictionary<string, object>`

Comment: You can deserialize the template JSON using a Dictionary, so you have the properties names as Keys. Then create a custom JsonConverter: in the `ReadJson` override, read the `TokenType` when it's `JsonToken.PropertyName`. At this time, you can check whether `Dictionary.ContainsKey()` (since the Keys store the properties names): if the Key is not found, then you skip that property (you don't deserialize it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deserialize the json to a class with the variables you are interested in. Anything not part of the class will be ignored

```
public class Rootobject
{
    [JsonProperty("age")]
    public int Age { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("interest")]
    public string Interest { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("address")]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("personalId")]
    public int PersonalId { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialize to the above class. You dont have to worry about removing anything from the json you are getting. once deserialized to the above class, you have the data you are interested in.

**Update**

You can use `JObject.Parse` if you dont want to create a class. You can look up the values (check if they exist as well) and create a new object that you can then save to wherever you need.

```
var obj = JObject.Parse(json);

dynamic objectToSaveToDB = new ExpandoObject();
objectToSaveToDB.age = obj.GetValue("age");
objectToSaveToDB.name = obj.GetValue("name");
objectToSaveToDB.interest = obj.GetValue("interest");
objectToSaveToDB.address = obj["address"].ToString();
objectToSaveToDB.personalId = obj["personalId"].ToString();

// String version would be JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectToSaveToDB);
```

Comment: I can't hardcode the base template. The base template is defined by system administrator and are uploaded in the platform then users upload their customer JSON based on the template defined by sys admin. So I can't hard code the base template in a class

Comment: you dont have to hardcode anything per say. When you receive the json, deserialize it to the above class, and then store it how you need to. Point is, when you deserialize the json to the above class, it will take the data based on the JsonProperties defined and ignore the rest of the stuff (which is what you were asking how to accomplish)

Comment: but "age" field could be named in a different way... The base template is a JSON I can't convert into a class because is defined by the administrator of the application and uploaded as a file to it.

Comment: Perhaps mentioning some of the work you have already done might help understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Actually I'm stucked on this point entirely. I have only the upload procedure and parsing to DB of the JSON base template, and the upload procedure of the users files... but I don't know how to solve the issue of my question... If you say the class is not hardcoded, you mean there's a way to create a dynamic class of the RootObject?

Comment: You can parse it using JObject.Parse and create a new object that you would save to DB. See my update in the response